# Why are my env variables undefined in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

I want to keep my key and base variable inside of .env , but when I assign them to .env and console.log it variables are undefined.

App file

```
# App.js
import './style/App.css';
import Main from './components/Main';
import './style/Search.css'
import { useState } from 'react';
import Error from './components/Error';
import api from './config'

function App() {
  console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_KEY)


  return (
    <div>
       
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Env file

```
# .env

REACT_APP_KEY=somevalue123
REACT_APP_BASE=somelink
```

Comment: When React runs in a browser, there is no `process`.

Comment: @FZs  if the OP is using a bundler, then process.env may well exist.   It's just that he's likely wanting to use something like this -> https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/

Comment: When I host it on netlify and add environment variables, it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

So the way I solved this was by doing the following...

1. install the dotenv package "npm i dotenv"
2. then you have to import it and also configure it, like below

> import dotenv from "dotenv"
> dotenv.config();
> 3. then you should be able to use your env variables

**NOTE**: you should restart your npm server every time you import a new env variable